# Console.ReadLine() never called from Visual Studio build events

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have written a small support console program that is supposed to handle versioning of other programs in the pre/post build of visual studio through user input.

I.e. the user is supposed to get prompted how he/she wants to version the build.
So in my pre/post I have something like "version.exe $(ProjectDir)".

However, `version.exe` crashes with a null reference exception to the following line (denoted with an arrow)

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
bool result = input.Substring(0,1).ToUpper() == trueKey; <---- input is null
```

the user is never prompted.

What is wrong?

Comment: I have post build events which call an executable, though I never see a window, so I assume that VS is hiding it.  That said, there are much better ways to do versioning than relying on manual input.

Comment: Can you provide a hint to these ways?

Answer (score 4):

The `Console.ReadLine` method can return a `null` value if the input stream has no more data available.  You can simulate this from a simple console program by hitting `Ctrl+Z` whenever it is waiting for input.

It's possible that the programs started by the build simply disallow input by closing down the input stream.  This would be a preventative measure for builds blocking waiting for user input

Another way to approach this is to use an MSBuild setting.  Essentially have a build configuration for a versioned and unversioned build.  Enable this build step only if the versioned build is enabled and remove the need for user input.

Comment: I see. My "problem" is that I'm switching to semantic versioning and the user has to deside whether the major, minor or patch version is to be updated. This would require 3 different build configurations which is a bit cumbersome.